# i want to check if the specified condition is true at least one time for the given number of bars starting from the current one in PineScript

Tags: pine-script

```
condition = (ta.barssince(high > sma20 or high > sma50 or high > sma200) <= 3) and (ta.barssince(close < sma20 or close < sma50 or close < sma200) <= 3)

// Plotting for visualization
plotshape(condition, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small)
```

Is this one correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `math.sum()` to count the number of times where a condition was `true` within the given lookback period.

```
cond = (close > open)

lookback = 5
cond_cnt = math.sum(cond ? 1 : 0, lookback)
```

Comment: Can i look lookhead also?